# How to maintain Lite version of application in Windows Store?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm planning a classic marketing model of my application: full-featured, paid application and smaller, "Lite" version with cut functionality.

Of course, the lite version will share quite large code base with full version - along with some views. Also, all modifications and fixes to the full version in areas available to the "Lite" version should be updated in that version as well. The question is: how to maintain both application versions at once?

Of course, manual copying/editing files is out of question.

My current, best (so far) idea is:

1. Create additional project (I'll need that to create new application package anyway)
2. Link files from the original project
3. Set the compilation constant "Lite" in the lite version
4. Use conditional compilation to cut off some features

This does not cover, however, XAML files, because they do not support conditional compilation (and I'm using Express version of VS, so I cannot install any extensions). So for XAML files the idea is to:

5. Derive all ViewModels from the same base class
6. Publish property called "LiteVisibility" with value controlled via conditional compilation (Visible vs Collapsed)
7. Bind parts of XAML, which should not be available in lite version to this property.

Another option is to create completely different XAML files for the lite version, but that's the option I'd like to avoid.

Is there any better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Hide xaml features from the code. I do the same. But why you want to create another package? I use only different configuration.

Comment: Is that possible? I have to create the .xapp package, can I do that in the same project?

Comment: Yes, why not? I use this technique in Windows Phone project. Create packages from the different configurations and submit to the different apps in the store dashboard.

Comment: Care to comment on downvote? (whoever downvoted)

Comment: I would Like to know the final solution you used :)